# Angular Material - How to set value to the Mat Date Range Picker

Tags: angular, angular-material, momentjs, angular-reactive-forms, mat-datepicker

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="date-picker" style="margin-right: auto;">
        <mat-label>یک بازه زمانی انتخاب کنید</mat-label>
        <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="rangePicker">
            <input matInput #dateRangeStart matStartDate placeholder="تاریخ شروع" formControlName="fromDate">
            <input matInput #dateRangeEnd matEndDate placeholder="تاریخ پایان" formControlName="toDate">
        </mat-date-range-input>
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="rangePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-date-range-picker #rangePicker>
                <mat-date-range-picker-actions>
                    <button mat-button matDateRangePickerCancel>کنسل</button>
                    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" matDateRangePickerApply (click)="onFormSubmit()">تایید</button>
                </mat-date-range-picker-actions>
            </mat-date-range-picker>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

I define form like this

```js
initForm() {
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    fromDate: new FormControl(),
    toDate: new FormControl()
  });
}
```

and want to set value from ts file like this

```js
if (filterModel.fromCreateDate && filterModel.toCreateDate) { 
 
  this.form.get('fromDate')?.setValue(this.convertToMiladi(filterModel.fromCreateDate));

  this.form.get('toDate')?.setValue(this.convertToMiladi(filterModel.toCreateDate));
}
```

How do I convert to miladi is like this

```js
convertToMiladi(date: string) {
  let convertableDate = moment(date).locale('en').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  var m = moment(convertableDate, 'jYYYY-jMM-jDM');
  m = m.locale('en')
  return m.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
}
```

and I have an adapter for calendar

```js
import { Inject, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import { DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';
import * as jMoment from 'moment-jalaali';
const minmin: any = jMoment;

export const PERSIAN_DATE_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: "jYYYY/jMM/jDD"
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: "jYYYY/jMM/jDD",
    monthYearLabel: "jYYYY jMMMM",
    dateA11yLabel: "jYYYY/jMM/jDD",
    monthYearA11yLabel: "jYYYY jMMMM"
  }
};

export class JalaliMomentDateAdapter extends DateAdapter<jMoment.Moment> {
  constructor(@Optional() @Inject(MAT_DATE_LOCALE) matDateLocale: string) {
    super();
    this.setLocale(matDateLocale || minmin.locale('fa'));
    minmin.loadPersian();
  }

  invalid() {
    return 'hi' as any;

  }

  toIso8601(date) {
    return 'hi';

  }

  /**
   * returns year in jalali calendar system.
   */
  getYear(date: jMoment.Moment): number {
    return this.clone(date).jYear();
  }

  /**
   * returns month in jalali calendar system.
   */
  getMonth(date: jMoment.Moment): number {
    return this.clone(date).jMonth();
  }

  /**
   * returns day in jalali calendar system.
   */
  getDate(date: jMoment.Moment): number {
    return this.clone(date).jDate();
  }

  /**
   * returns Day Of Week in jalali calendar system.
   */
  getDayOfWeek(date: jMoment.Moment): number {
    return this.clone(date).day();
  }

  /**
   * returns Month Names in jalali calendar system.
   * most of the time we use long format. short or narrow format for month names is a little odd.
   */
  getMonthNames(style: 'long' | 'short' | 'narrow'): string[] {
    const r: string[] = [];
    minmin.loadPersian({ dialect: 'persian-modern', usePersianDigits: true });
    const l = minmin().localeData();
    if (style === 'long' || style === 'short') {
      Object.keys(l).forEach(key => {
        if (key === '_jMonths') {
          const values = l[key];
          for (let index = 0; index < values.length; index++) {
            r.push(values[index]);
          }
        }
      });
    } else {
      Object.keys(l).forEach(key => {
        if (key === '_jMonthsShort') {
          const values = l[key];
          for (let index = 0; index < values.length; index++) {
            r.push(values[index]);
          }
        }
      });
    }
    return r;
    // switch (style) {
    //     case 'long':
    //         const mlong = (minmin().localeData() as any)._jMonths.slice(0);
    //         console.log(mlong);
    //         return mlong;
    //     case 'short':
    //         const mshort = (minmin().localeData() as any)._jMonthsShort.slice(0);
    //         console.log('mshort: ', mshort);
    //         return mshort;
    //     case 'narrow':
    //         return (minmin().localeData() as any)._jMonthsShort.slice(0);
    // }
  }

  /**
   * borrowed from angular material code.
   */
  getDateNames(): string[] {
    return this.range(31, i => String(i + 1));
  }

  /**
   * returns Day Of Week names in jalali calendar system.
   */
  getDayOfWeekNames(style: 'long' | 'short' | 'narrow'): string[] {
    switch (style) {
      case 'long':
        return minmin().localeData().weekdays().slice(0);
      case 'short':
        return minmin().localeData().weekdaysShort().slice(0);
      case 'narrow':
        return minmin().localeData().weekdaysMin().slice(0);
    }
  }

  /**
   * returns year in jalali calendar system.
   */
  getYearName(date: jMoment.Moment): string {
    return this.clone(date).jYear().toString();
  }

  /**
   * returns first day of week in jalali calendar system.
   * first day of week is saturday, شنبه
   */
  getFirstDayOfWeek(): number {
    return 6;
  }

  /**
   * returns Number of Days In Month in jalali calendar system.
   */
  getNumDaysInMonth(date: jMoment.Moment, fa?): number {
    if (date['_d']) {
      return minmin.jDaysInMonth(this.getYear(date['_d']), this.getMonth(date['_d']));
    }
    return minmin.jDaysInMonth(this.getYear(date), this.getMonth(date));
  }

  clone(date: jMoment.Moment): jMoment.Moment {
    // return date.clone().locale(this.locale);
    return minmin(date);
  }

  createDate(year: number, month: number, date: number): jMoment.Moment {
    return minmin().jYear(year).jMonth(month).jDate(date);
  }

  today(): jMoment.Moment {
    return minmin();
  }

  parse(value: any, parseFormat: string | string[]): jMoment.Moment | null {
    if (value && typeof value === 'string') {
      return minmin(value, parseFormat, this.locale);
    }
    return value ? minmin(value).locale(this.locale) : null;
  }

  format(date: jMoment.Moment, displayFormat: any): string {
    return this.clone(date).format(displayFormat);
  }

  addCalendarYears(date: jMoment.Moment, years: number): jMoment.Moment {
    return this.clone(date).add(years, 'jYear');
  }

  addCalendarMonths(date: jMoment.Moment, months: number): jMoment.Moment {
    return this.clone(date).add(months as any, 'jmonth');
  }

  addCalendarDays(date: jMoment.Moment, days: number): jMoment.Moment {
    return this.clone(date).add(days, 'day');
  }

  getISODateString(date: jMoment.Moment): string {
    return this.clone(date).format('jYYYY-jMM-jDD');
  }

  isDateInstance(obj: any): boolean {
    return minmin.isMoment(obj);
  }

  isValid(date: jMoment.Moment): boolean {
    return this.clone(date).isValid();
  }

  range<T>(length: number, valueFunction: (index: number) => T): T[] {
    const valuesArray = Array(length);
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      valuesArray[i] = valueFunction(i);
    }
    return valuesArray;
  }
}
```

I try to set value but my date range picker is empty after patchValue or setValue in Angular reactive forms.
Can someone help me set the value for the mat date range picker from the .ts file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your `JalaliMomentDateAdapter` extends `DateAdapter<T>` with `T` is `jMoment.Moment`.

Hence, you need to **set the value with `jMoment.Moment` type** to `FormControl`.

```js
convertToMiladi(date: string) {
  // Match the date format with the format of parsed date 
  return moment(date, 'YYYY/MM/DD');
}
```

[Sample demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yyt5ev?file=src/app/app.component.ts)